# Java compile warning

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

While building a JAR file (successfully) in `Netbeans 7.1.1`, I encountered this warning:

```
...
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 warning
...
```

What does this mean? Also, does the Java runtime affect the compatibility of the JAR (application)?

When I run the JAR in `XP` and `Ubuntu`, the application seems fine, but when I try to run it on `Fedora`, it doesn't use the full screen and has no context menu when I right click on a `JTable`. What should I do about this?

**Some code snippets:**

This code calls a JFrame a setting it to fullscreen when loaded but this doesn't work in Fedora.

```
this.setVisible(false);
frmMain xForm = new frmMain();

xForm.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
GraphicsEnvironment e = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();

xForm.setMaximizedBounds(e.getMaximumWindowBounds());
xForm.setExtendedState(xForm.getExtendedState()|JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH );
xForm.setVisible(true);
```

When I right click the `JTable` to show a contextmenu works fine in `Windows`  but not in `fedora` and `Ubuntu`.

```
private void tableItemMouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                        

    if ( SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton( evt ))
    {
        int r = tableItem.rowAtPoint(evt.getPoint());
        if (r >= 0 && r < tableItem.getRowCount())
        {
            tableItem.setRowSelectionInterval(r, r);
        } 
        else 
        {
            tableItem.clearSelection();
        }

        int rowindex = tableItem.getSelectedRow();
        if (rowindex < 0)
            return;

        if (evt.isPopupTrigger() && evt.getComponent() instanceof JTable ) 
        {
            pmItem.show(evt.getComponent(), evt.getX(), evt.getY());
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 1**

by adding `-Xlint:unchecked` in Compile options, I got this warnings:

```
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6

C:\Documents and Settings\Totet\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\DCWD_DepreciationMonitoringSystem\src\DCWDDMS\frmItemDepreciation.java:432: 
warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to addElement(E) as a member of the raw type Vector
                newRow.addElement(rs.getObject(i));
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in class Vector

C:\Documents and Settings\Totet\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\DCWD_DepreciationMonitoringSystem\src\DCWDDMS\frmMain.java:351: 
warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to addElement(E) as a member of the raw type Vector
                newRow.addElement(rs.getObject(i));
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in class Vector

C:\Documents and Settings\Totet\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\DCWD_DepreciationMonitoringSystem\src\DCWDDMS\frmNewItem.java:831: 
warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to addElement(E) as a member of the raw type DefaultComboBoxModel
                    model.addElement(resultList.getString(1));
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in class DefaultComboBoxModel

C:\Documents and Settings\Totet\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\DCWD_DepreciationMonitoringSystem\src\DCWDDMS\frmNewItem.java:833: 
warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to setModel(ComboBoxModel<E>) as a member of the raw type JComboBox
                cmbAccount.setModel(model);
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in class JComboBox

5 warnings
```

Comment: It's hard to know what is going on when we can't see your code.

Comment: How are you building? ant, maven, Netbeans, eclipse or good old Javac ? This looks to me as if you have a project source JDK version setsomewhere but you are building with a different JDK. The other warning "unsafe operations" can be due to different reasons such as adding an element to an arraylist wihout checking its type etc. On Fedora check your path to make sure you are not running the default GNU Java run time.

Comment: Use `javac -Xlint` to see the unchecked or unsafe operations.

Comment: @ringbearer I'm using Netbeans 7.1

Comment: Java is a strongly typed language, looks like your complaints are about using 'Object' with out checking what it actually is. It's not always something to worry about, but post the code and a bit surrounding for more help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Source/Binary format setting**

Here is explicit way to set source and target of your project explicitly. Most of the time, you do not need to fiddle with this, once you set up your project specific Java platform in netbeans.

1. Right-click on Project and select Properties
2. Select Sources
3. Set the source level to 6 (Source/Binary format)
4. Click the OK button.

**Unsafe operations warning**

I generally ignore the "unsafe operation warning". But if you want to know why it is shown, do recompile with `-Xlint:unchecked` option (at step 5 above) and it will explain what and why is reported as unsafe.

**UI issues in Fedora**

On Fedora check your path to make sure you are not running the default GNU Java run time.

go to command line and type

`java -version`
to see what it returns. It must return Oracle's (sun) java information. Otherwise you will face issues especially with Swing/UI stuff.

Comment: I'll give this a try. Thank you. Oh, I added some generated warnings. Hope you have an idead how to solve that.. :)

Comment: I went to Sources => Source/Binary format: and found only this JDK `1.2`, `1.3`, `1.4`, `5`, `6`, `7`. There's no `1.6`, do I need to download and install it?

Comment: I never thought 1.6 is no 6. hehe do you have any idea how to solve this? warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to addElement(E) as a member of the raw type Vector
                `newRow.addElement(rs.getObject(i));`
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in class Vector

Comment: Ok, first of all, you may ignore that warning. But if you want to get rid of it, read up on Java generics (a feature of j2se 5) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java

Comment: one more thing, why is the pop up menu not showing on Linux? it works on Windows.

Comment: Did you check if you are running Oracle(sun) jvm or the default gnu java run time?

Comment: I only use `jexec` to run my JAR application. So what is that `jexec`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9091/discussion-between-ring-bearer-and-johntotetwoo)

Answer (score 4):

`javac` will happily adapt to a given `-source` release and generate `-target` compatible class files, but it can't know that you haven't inadvertently used an inappropriate feature unless you tell it what JDK to use. Typically, an IDE allows you to choose among installed JDK versions to mitigate the risk.

Addendum: In NetBeans, you can specify the `Java Platform` in `File > Project Properties > Library`.

Addendum: [`ComboBoxModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ComboBoxModel.html) became generic in Java 7. As you are targeting 1.6, you'll need to install the corresponding JDK. NetBeans should find it on startup and display it among the `Tools > Java Platforms`.

Addendum: Should you elect to target Java 7, there's a related example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9441109/230513).

Comment: I've elaborated above concerning NetBeans. What Java platforms are installed?

Comment: pardon me if this question is a little simple for you but hard for me because I'm a .net Developer and this is my first time to develop on Java so I don't have any idea what's going on. I added some warnings, hope you can help me on this.. thank you :)

Comment: sir, do you have any idea how to solve this? warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to addElement(E) as a member of the raw type Vector
                `newRow.addElement(rs.getObject(i));` where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in class Vector

Comment: More above; if you're going forward on 1.7, I'll try to find an example.