# I have a JFrame GUI (using the GUI builder) with a List [JList] from the swing controls but can't call setListData(Object[]) without an error

Tags: java, swing, jlist

Everything works perfectly fine when I am running the program within netbeans.
However, when I try to build the project to create a Jar file of it, every single line that has setListData(Object[]) called results in the following error:

```
warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to setListData(E[]) as a member of the raw
  type JList jList1.setListData(people.allStudentsAttendance());
  where E is a type-variable: E extends Object declared in class JList
```

I have purposely unchecked the -Xlint because I was getting error of:

```
Note: L:\Attendance\src\Attendance\AttendGUI.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: L:\Attendance\src\Attendance\AttendGUI.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

before I unchecked it and began trying to debug the error. The Jar file does not work and I have not been able to figure out how to fix this problem after a couple days of searching. Thank you in advance

Here is my code for the GUI~~

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
package Attendance;


public class AttendGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

private Model people = new Model();

private int toggleChecker = 0;

    /** Creates new form AttendGUI */
    public AttendGUI() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /** This method is called from within the constructor to
     * initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
     * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton5 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton7 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jList1 = new javax.swing.JList();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jPasswordField1 = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jList2 = new javax.swing.JList();
        jButton6 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jToggleButton1 = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
        jCheckBox1 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        jButton8 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jTextField3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton1.setText("Add Student");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jTextField1.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.CENTER);
        jTextField1.setText("Enter Full Name");
        jTextField1.addFocusListener(new java.awt.event.FocusAdapter() {
            public void focusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
                jTextField1FocusGained(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton2.setText("Remove Student");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton3.setText("Sign In");
        jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jTextField2.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.CENTER);
        jTextField2.setText(people.getDate());

        jButton4.setText("Remove Time");
        jButton4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton4ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton5.setText("Display All Students");
        jButton5.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton5ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton7.setText("Display Attendence of:");
        jButton7.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton7ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jList1);

        jLabel1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(51, 51, 255));
        jLabel1.setText("A password is required to remove information:");

        jList2.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Currently Selected"));
        jList2.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel() {
            String[] strings = { "none" };
            public int getSize() { return strings.length; }
            public Object getElementAt(int i) { return strings[i]; }
        });
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jList2);

        jButton6.setText("Display Tech Work of:");
        jButton6.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton6ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jToggleButton1.setText("Adding Drama Club Attendance");
        jToggleButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jToggleButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jCheckBox1.setText("Add Different Date");

        jButton8.setText("Select Student:");
        jButton8.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton8ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jTextField3.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.CENTER);
        jTextField3.setText("Enter Full Name");
        jTextField3.addFocusListener(new java.awt.event.FocusAdapter() {
            public void focusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
                jTextField3FocusGained(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 12));
        jLabel2.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(51, 51, 255));
        jLabel2.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jLabel2.setText("Select Yourself Here");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 111, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 183, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        .addGap(11, 11, 11)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 167, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 167, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jButton4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 167, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                    .addComponent(jButton5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 361, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addComponent(jToggleButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 226, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 226, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jCheckBox1)
                            .addComponent(jPasswordField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 129, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jButton8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 166, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jButton7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 177, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jButton6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 177, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 158, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 174, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 146, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(110, 110, 110)))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 233, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jButton1)
                            .addComponent(jButton3))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jButton2)
                            .addComponent(jButton4))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jToggleButton1)
                            .addComponent(jCheckBox1))
                        .addGap(6, 6, 6)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1)
                            .addComponent(jPasswordField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jButton5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 42, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(4, 4, 4)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jButton8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 28, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 12, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 75, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jButton7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 33, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(jButton6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 36, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))))
                .addContainerGap(15, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    people.addStudent(jTextField1.getText());
    jList1.setListData(people.allStudentsAttendance());
    String[] sel = {people.getSelected()};
    jList2.setListData(sel);
}                                        

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    if (true){
        people.removeStudent(jTextField1.getText());
        jList1.setListData(people.allStudentsAttendance());
        String[] sel = {"none"};
        jList2.setListData(sel);
    }
}                                        

private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    String time;
    if (toggleChecker % 2 == 1){
        time = people.getDateTime();
        if (jCheckBox1.isSelected()){
            people.checkIn(jTextField2.getText());
        } else {
            people.checkIn(time);
        }
    } else {
        time = people.getDate();
        if (jCheckBox1.isSelected()){
            people.addAttend(jTextField2.getText());
        } else {
            people.addAttend(time);
        }
    }
    jTextField2.setText(time);
    if (toggleChecker % 2 == 1){
        jList1.setListData(people.viewTechHours());
    } else {
        jList1.setListData(people.viewAttendance());
    }
}                                        

private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    if (jPasswordField1.getText().equals("hello")){
        if (toggleChecker % 2 == 1){
            people.removeHours(jTextField2.getText());
        } else {
            people.removeAttend(jTextField2.getText());
        }
        jList1.setListData(people.viewAttendance());
    }
}                                        

private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    jList1.setListData(people.allStudentsAttendance());
}                                        

private void jButton7ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    jList1.setListData(people.viewAttendance());
}                                        

private void jTextField1FocusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {                                        

    jTextField1.setText("");
}                                       

private void jButton6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    jList1.setListData(people.viewTechHours());
}                                        

private void jToggleButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               

    toggleChecker++;
    if (toggleChecker % 2 == 1){
        jToggleButton1.setText("Adding Tech Hours");
        jTextField2.setText(people.getDateTime());
        jButton3.setText("Check In");
    } else{
        jToggleButton1.setText("Adding Drama Club Attendance");
        jTextField2.setText(people.getDate());
        jButton3.setText("Sign In");
        toggleChecker = 0;
    }
}                                              

private void jTextField3FocusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {                                        

    jTextField3.setText("");
}                                       

private void jButton8ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    people.selectStudent(jTextField3.getText());
    jList1.setListData(people.viewAttendance());
    String[] sel = {people.getSelected()};
    jList2.setListData(sel);
}                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AttendGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AttendGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AttendGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AttendGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new AttendGUI().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton5;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton6;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton7;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton8;
    private javax.swing.JCheckBox jCheckBox1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JList jList1;
    private javax.swing.JList jList2;
    private javax.swing.JPasswordField jPasswordField1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField3;
    private javax.swing.JToggleButton jToggleButton1;
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

Comment: this is a warning, not an error. it shouldn't stop you from building and running the jar. show what happens when you run the jar with `java -jar yourjar.jar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`JList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html) and it's [`DefaultListModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html) became [generic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) in Java 7. NetBeans suppresses the corresponding warning in code that it generates, but your code remains unchecked. You can either

- Add the `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` annotation as required,
- Revise the code to ensure type-safety, as suggested in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9441109/230513).

Comment: Thank you that solved the warning problem but I realize from Denis Tulskiy (Thank you) that my problem is in trying to run the jar.
When I run java -jar blahblah.jar I get the following:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainClassFromJar(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)


I tried setting the main class in the manifest file to AttendGUI already and nothing changed

Comment: What IDE? Can you edit your question to show your output, manifest and directory structure?

Comment: Netbeans IDE 7 //

Which output exactly? in the command prompt? //

Manifest-Version: 1.0
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
Main-Class: AttendGUI //

directory structure I left at its default

Comment: Do `Run > Clean and Build Project` then look in `dist` at `README.TXT`. This [utility](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/manifesto) will let you examine the JAR as built.