# found raw type, missing return arguments for generic class

Tags: java, swing, class, generics, netbeans

I don't understand this warning:

```java
found raw type: javax.swing.DefaultListModel
missing type arguements for generic class javax.swing.DefaultListModel
```

Netbeans seems to indicate that more information can be found from `alt-enter` but nothing comes up.  The type should be ?

[image]

code:

```java
package net.bounceme.dur.nntp.swing;

import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;

public class MessagesListModel extends DefaultListModel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(MessagesListModel.class.getName());

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void addElement(Object element) {
        super.addElement(element);
    }

}
```

Comment: A complete example may be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9441109/230513).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*DefaultListModel* is a [generic type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html) from *Java 7*.

You should do `DefaultListModel<ClassName>` instead of `DefaultListModel`.

Generally, this is more safe, since you specify what you should and what you shouldn't insert to the list. So if you made mistake, the compiler will arise an error.

Comment: which was why I was extending it in the first place.  Ok, good to know :)

Answer (score 1):

*From **Java 7** DefaultListModel is considered as Generic class*. See [DefaultListModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html) . And while extending it you are not providing generic type to the DefaultListModel that you are extending. That's why your IDE is warning you.
Either you could ignore this warning. or As alternative you provide some `Type parameter` to it like `<Integer>` `<String>` or anything.. for example.

```
public class MessagesListModel extends DefaultListModel<String>
```