# Type of elements in a listmodel

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jlist, defaultlistmodel

I have defined a custom `ListModel` as an inner class of some other class holding some data. To populate the `ListModel`, I query a database file and select the data in it, as shown in the piece of code below. Everything appears nicely in a `JList` using
this `ListModel`.

What I don't understand is the "use of unchecked or unsafe operations". When I compile with -Xlint, I get the warning:
"missing type arguments for generic class `DefaultListModel<E>`"

My questions is what is `<E>` in the first line of my code below:

```
public class SalListModel extends DefaultListModel<E=?>{

    String defaultSearch="*";
    String salName=defaultSearch;

    //inner class constructor
    public SalListModel(){

        try{

                //connection creates the database if it does not exist
                Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
                Connection c=
                    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:"+dbfile);
                Statement st=c.createStatement();

                String sql;
                sql="select "+salName+" from "+tablename+
                    " ORDER BY "+name[0]+" ASC;"; //alphabetical order
                ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(sql);

                while (rs.next()){
                     addElement(rs.getString(name[0])+" "+rs.getString(cnp[0]));
                }

                rs.close();
                st.close();
                c.close();
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe){
                 System.out.println("SQL SalListModel class not found: "+
                             cnfe.getMessage());
        }
        catch (SQLException sqle){
                System.out.println("SalListModel SQL exception:"+
                             sqle.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you have to use generic type, almost same question in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718217/found-raw-type-missing-return-arguments-for-generic-class

Comment: that answers my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have defined a custom ListModel

Why? You are not adding any new functionality to the model. Loading data into a model should not be considered new functionality. Just create a method in your class to load the data into the model. Then your code would be something like:

```
ListModel<String> model = new DefaultListModel<String>();
addDataToModel( model );
```

> My questions is what is `<E>` in the first line of my code below:

You are adding `String` data to the model so you should be using `DefaultListModel<String>`